# display value in the order I select value in dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have multi-select drop down  . Which ever I select it should be displayed in the textbox . The following code works fine. But I need the values in the textbox in the order I select in dropdown.

For example If I select 1st as WEST and 2nd as EAST, then the value in textbox should be WEST,EAST and not EAST,WEST. help me out please

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <select id="direction" class="direction" multiselect>
        <option value="west">WEST</option>
        <option value="east">EAST</option>
        <option value="south">SOUTH</option>
        <option value="north">NORTH</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

**JQUERY**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var grpby_arrayy = [];
     $('#direction').on("select change", function () {
         $("#direction option:selected").each(function (i) {
             grpby_arrayy[i] = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
             $("#grpbytxt" + aid).val(grpby_arrayy.join(","));
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: where is `"#grpbytxt"+aid`?

Answer (score 0):

so it would be something like this:

`grpby_arrayy.push($("#direction :selected").text());`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function()
     {
    var grpby_arrayy=[];
    $('#direction').on("select change",function () {
         $("#direction option:selected").each(function(i){
             grpby_arrayy.push($(this).val().toUpperCase());

         }); 
        $("#grpbytxt"+aid).val(grpby_arrayy);
      });
    });`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
    var grpby_arrayy=[];
    $('#direction').on("select change",function () {    

         grpby_arrayy.push($("#direction option:selected").val().toUpperCase());         
         console.log(grpby_arrayy);;
      });
 });
```

please try above code. array.push will solve your problem.